# Xcode Swift Group Table color scheme

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to set the color of the bottom view to matches the scrollview

[image]

scrollview is set to color *Group Table View Background Color*

but in the view color doesn't have this as an option and every gray color is either too dark or too light

Comment: I can see this in Xcode 11.7 https://imgur.com/a/QMCZu5Q - What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: @TarunTyagi its version 12.0.1

Comment: May be a bug. Try quitting and reopening the Xcode. If it doesn't work. Try switching to an old installation like Xcode 11.7 if that's an option for you. Otherwise upgrade to Xcode 12.2

Comment: Thank you! found that *System Grouped Background Color* is the same color a matches it